# Adding a Play Again Option in a C++ Dice Game Program that Enables Players to Play until There is a Winner

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ as I am trying to learn from my mistakes. I am writing a dice game program that has several conditions and enables the two players to play until there is a winner. I have tried reading about ways to implement the "play until there is a winner rather than stop when it is a draw" option. However, I did not come up with something that worked. I have tried making my else block looking like this:

```
else
          {
              cout<< "Player 1: " << p1 << "-" << p1s << endl;
              cout<< "Player 2: " << p2 << "-" << p2s << endl;
              cout<< "Tie! \n";
              return main; // I am wanting the game to restart automatically when they draw. So that is what I did.

          }
```

The reason I did that is because I want it to declare the players drew and wanted it to restart. How should I start writing it? Thanks, and here is my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    cout << " -- Barbooth dice-rolling game with 2 players –" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    
    int numOne = 1;
    int numTwo = 2; 
    int numThree = 3;
    int numFour = 4;
    int numFive = 5;
    int numSix = 6; 
    
    int p1 = (rand() % 6) + 1; //First throw for player one
    cout << "Player 1, please enter to roll." << endl;
    cout << "Player 1: " << p1 << endl;
    
    
    int p2 = (rand() % 6) + 1; //First throw for player two
    cout << "Player 2, please enter to roll." << endl;
    cout << "Player 2: " << p2 << endl;
    
    int p1s = (rand() % 6) + 1; //Second throw for player one
    int p2s = (rand() % 6) + 1; //Second throw for player 4
    cout << endl;
    
    if(p1 > p2)
    {
        cout << "Player 1, please enter to roll." << endl;
        cout << "Player 1: " << p1s << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Player 2, please enter to roll." << endl;
        cout << "Player 2: " << p2s << endl;
    }
    
    cout << endl; 
    

    if(p1 == numThree && p1s == numThree)
      {
        cout<< "Player 1: " << p1 << "-" << p1s << endl;
        cout<< "Player 1 wins\n";
      }
     else if(p1 == numFive && p1s == numFive)
      {
        cout<< "Player 1: " << p1 << "-" << p1s << endl;
        cout<< "Player 1 wins\n";  
      }
     else if(p1 == numSix && p1s == numSix)
      {
        cout<< "Player 1: " << p1 << "-" << p1s << endl;
        cout<< "Player 1 wins\n";  
      }
     else if(p1 == numSix && p1s == numFive)
      {
        cout<< "Player 1: " << p1 << "-" << p1s << endl;
        cout<< "Player 1 wins\n";  
      }
     else if(p1 == numOne && p1s == numOne)
      {
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(p1 == numTwo && p1s == numTwo)
      {
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(p1 == numFour && p1s == numFour)
      {
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(p1 == numOne && p1s == numTwo)
      {
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(p2 == numThree && p2s == numThree)
      {
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(p2 == numFive && p2s == numFive)
      {
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(p2 == numSix && p2s == numSix)
      {
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(p2 == numSix && p2s == numFive)
      {
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
      else if(p2 == numOne && p2s == numOne)
      {
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(p2 == numTwo && p2s == numTwo)
      {
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(p2 == numFour && p2s == numFour)
      {
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(p2 == numOne && p2s == numTwo)
      {
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
      
      else
      {
          cout<< "Player 1: " << p1 << "-" << p1s << endl;
          cout<< "Player 2: " << p2 << "-" << p2s << endl;
          cout<< "Tie! \n";
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get desired effect using simple while loop with boolean variable.
This loop will continue until you don't change gamefinished variable in one of your winning states.

```
bool gamefinished = false
while(!gamefinished) {

    int p1 = (rand() % 6) + 1; //First throw for player one
    cout << "Player 1, please enter to roll." << endl;
    cout << "Player 1: " << p1 << endl;
    
    
    int p2 = (rand() % 6) + 1; //First throw for player two
    cout << "Player 2, please enter to roll." << endl;
    cout << "Player 2: " << p2 << endl;
    
    int p1s = (rand() % 6) + 1; //Second throw for player one
    int p2s = (rand() % 6) + 1; //Second throw for player 4
    cout << endl;

    if(p1 == numThree && p1s == numThree)
      {
        cout<< "Player 1: " << p1 << "-" << p1s << endl;
        cout<< "Player 1 wins\n";
        gamefinished = true;
      }
     else if(p1 == numFive && p1s == numFive)
      {
        cout<< "Player 1: " << p1 << "-" << p1s << endl;
        cout<< "Player 1 wins\n";  
        gamefinished = true;
      }
/// rest of your non draw cases
.
.
.
      else
      {
          cout<< "Player 1: " << p1 << "-" << p1s << endl;
          cout<< "Player 2: " << p2 << "-" << p2s << endl;
          cout<< "Tie! \n";
          //don't change your bool variable here so loop will go for
          //another iteration
      }
}
```

Also. I'm not sure why you defined integers as variables

```
if(p1 == 1 && p1s == 5)
```

is as valid as your code but shorter